# How to access pipeline variable through java code?

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to access azure pipeline variables through java code but no luck.

I am using below code to access **env.id** and **env.password**.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String id = System.getenv("${env.id}");
    String password = System.getenv("${env.password}");

    System.out.printf("Enviornment Id:: "+id );
    System.out.printf("Enviornment Password :: "+password );
        
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the below findings helpful to resolve the issue:
`System.getenv` method takes the string arguments and you could try the below syntax for getting the environment variable values in Java:

```java
String id = System.getenv(" + "env.id" + ");
String password = System.getenv(" + "env.password" + ");
```

(OR)

```java
    System.out.printf("System.getenv("env_var");
```

Refer to this Similar SO [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59415072/how-do-you-access-azure-pipelines-variables-in-a-java-maven-project) for more information on accessing the azure pipelines variables using Java given by @*LeviLu-MSFT*.

Comment: I have tried this but no luck